# Inject super class to raw object by generating constructor

Tags: typescript

I'm making a library written in Typescript2.0 and that can be used from javascript also.

I have a class `Component` and a function `registerComponent` which is made by Typescript.

I need to store constructor of classes which inherits `Component` by calling `registerComponent`. And registered components can be instanciated automatically by my library.
In some case, the argument of the method could be not a function but a object. I need to convert object to a constructor function generating passed object.

But, that constructor should extends `Component` class also.
So, I mean I want to inject a class as super class to a function which would generate given object with typescript.

This is the section to handle raw objects in registerComponent .

```js
const newCtor = function() {
  Component.call(this);
};
const properties = {};
for (let key in obj) {
  properties[key] = { value: obj[key] };
}
newCtor.prototype = Object.create(Component.prototype, properties);
return newCtor;
```

`obj` is given plain object by user. I thought this code would work but actually this code populate a error `Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor Component cannot be invoked without 'new'` when I used the constructor with new keyword.
And that exception is thrown on the code `Component.call(this)`.

How can I make valid constructor with injecting super class?

---

I'm very sorry to ask in such ambiguous post. But now I think I need to post full interface I want to achive.

```js
class Component{
    public baseFunction():string
    {
        return "This is base";
    }
}
class Registory{
   private static registeredConstructors:{[key:string]:(new()=>Component)};

   public static registerComponent(name:string,c:(new()=>Component)|{[key:string]:any}):void
   {
       if(typeof c === "function")
       {
           Registory.registeredConstructors[name] = c;
           return;
       }else{
           // Assume c is plain object
           // I need some code here to wrap c as constructor
       }
   }

   public static instanciate(name:string):Component
   {
       return new Registory.registeredContructors[name]();
   }
}

// When User want to register component via Typescript class

class C1 extends Component{
   public someProperty:string = "HELLO C1";

   public f1():string{
      return this.baseFunction() + this.someProperty;
   }
}

Registory.registerComponent("C1",C1);
const c1:Component = Registory.instanciate("C1");

// When user want to register component via plain object

Registory.registerComponent("C2",{
    someProperty:"Hello C2",
    f1:function(){
        return this.baseFunction() + this.someProperty;
    }
});
const c2:Component = Registory.instanciate("C2");

// This is the test c1 and c2 should pass

test.true(()=>c1 instanceof Component);
test.true(()=>c2 instanceof Component);
test.true(()=>c1.f1() === "This is base Hello C1");
test.true(()=>c2.f1() === "This is base Hello C2");
test.true(()=>c1 instanceof C1);
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do, for example you have `for (let key in obj)` but what is this `obj`? What is the purpose of the `registerComponent` function?

Comment: My apologies. But, I edited my post. And ,'obj' is plain object I want to convert constructor inheriting `Component`. `registerComponent` is a method to register constructors to library, and library would instanciate them later if that component is needed.

Comment: The code you added is not valid at all. A few example: (1) `Component. baseFunction` suppose to return `void`, but the implementation returns a `string`.  (2) What is `registeredConstructors:[ {key:string]: (new()=>Component);`? You start it with `[` but it never closes. Can you fix it?

Comment: I fixed that. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that your scenario can be solved more easily, if I understand you correctly:

```
abstract class Component {
    constructor(props: any) {}
}

type ComponentConstructor = {
    new (props: any): Component;
    name: string;
};

const REGISTRY = {} as { [name: string]: ComponentConstructor };
function registerComponent(ctor: ComponentConstructor) {
    REGISTRY[ctor.name] = ctor;
}

function instantiateComponent(name: string, props: any): Component;
function instantiateComponent<T extends Component>(name: string, props: any): T {
    if (typeof REGISTRY[name] !== "function") {
        return null;
    }

    return new REGISTRY[name](props) as T;
}

class MyComponent1 extends Component { }
registerComponent(MyComponent1);

class MyComponent2 extends Component { }
registerComponent(MyComponent2);

let comp1 = instantiateComponent("MyComponent1", {}); // typeof comp1 is Component
let comp2: MyComponent2 = instantiateComponent("MyComponent2", {}); // typeof comp2 is MyComponent2
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=abstract%20class%20Component%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(props%3A%20any)%20%7B%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Atype%20ComponentConstructor%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20new%20(props%3A%20any)%3A%20Component%3B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aconst%20REGISTRY%20%3D%20%7B%7D%20as%20%7B%20%5Bname%3A%20string%5D%3A%20ComponentConstructor%20%7D%3B%0Afunction%20registerComponent(ctor%3A%20ComponentConstructor)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20REGISTRY%5Bctor.name%5D%20%3D%20ctor%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20instantiateComponent(name%3A%20string%2C%20props%3A%20any)%3A%20Component%3B%0Afunction%20instantiateComponent%3CT%20extends%20Component%3E(name%3A%20string%2C%20props%3A%20any)%3A%20T%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(typeof%20REGISTRY%5Bname%5D%20!%3D%3D%20%22function%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20null%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20return%20new%20REGISTRY%5Bname%5D(props)%20as%20T%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20MyComponent1%20extends%20Component%20%7B%20%7D%0AregisterComponent(MyComponent1)%3B%0A%0Aclass%20MyComponent2%20extends%20Component%20%7B%20%7D%0AregisterComponent(MyComponent2)%3B%0A%0Alet%20comp1%20%3D%20instantiateComponent(%22MyComponent1%22%2C%20%7B%7D)%3B%20%2F%2F%20typeof%20comp1%20is%20Component%0Alet%20comp2%3A%20MyComponent2%20%3D%20instantiateComponent(%22MyComponent2%22%2C%20%7B%7D)%3B%20%2F%2F%20typeof%20comp2%20is%20MyComponent2))

---

#### Edit

Ok, now that I understand what you want, it's easier to help.
I still had to clean up your code, but here's what you want:

```
interface IComponent {
    someProperty: string;
    f1(): string;
}

abstract class Component implements IComponent {
    abstract someProperty: string;
    abstract f1(): string;

    public baseFunction(): string {
        return "This is base ";
    }
}

type ComponentConstructor = { new (): Component };

abstract class ComponentFromObject extends Component {
    constructor(obj: IComponent) {
        super();

        Object.assign(this, obj);
    }
}

class Registory {
    private static registeredConstructors: { [key: string]: ComponentConstructor } = {};

    public static registerComponent(name: string, c: ComponentConstructor | IComponent): void {
        if (typeof c === "function") {
            Registory.registeredConstructors[name] = c;
        } else {
            Registory.registeredConstructors[name] = ComponentFromObject.bind(null, c);
        }
    }

    public static instanciate(name: string): Component {
        return new Registory.registeredConstructors[name]();
    }
}
const registory = new Registory();

// When User want to register component via Typescript class

class C1 extends Component {
    public someProperty: string = "Hello C1";

    public f1(): string {
        return this.baseFunction() + this.someProperty;
    }
}

Registory.registerComponent("C1", C1);
const c1: Component = Registory.instanciate("C1");

// When user want to register component via plain object

Registory.registerComponent("C2", {
    someProperty: "Hello C2",
    f1: function(){
        return this.baseFunction() + this.someProperty;
    }
});
const c2: Component = Registory.instanciate("C2");

// This is the test c1 and c2 should pass

console.log(c1 instanceof Component);
console.log(c2 instanceof Component);
console.log(c1.f1() === "This is base Hello C1");
console.log(c2.f1() === "This is base Hello C2");
console.log(c1 instanceof C1);
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IComponent%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20someProperty%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20f1()%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aabstract%20class%20Component%20implements%20IComponent%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20abstract%20someProperty%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20abstract%20f1()%3A%20string%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20public%20baseFunction()%3A%20string%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22This%20is%20base%20%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Atype%20ComponentConstructor%20%3D%20%7B%20new%20()%3A%20Component%20%7D%3B%0A%0Aabstract%20class%20ComponentFromObject%20extends%20Component%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(obj%3A%20IComponent)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super()%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Object.assign(this%2C%20obj)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Registory%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20private%20static%20registeredConstructors%3A%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20ComponentConstructor%20%7D%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20public%20static%20registerComponent(name%3A%20string%2C%20c%3A%20ComponentConstructor%20%7C%20IComponent)%3A%20void%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(typeof%20c%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22function%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Registory.registeredConstructors%5Bname%5D%20%3D%20c%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Registory.registeredConstructors%5Bname%5D%20%3D%20ComponentFromObject.bind(null%2C%20c)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20public%20static%20instanciate(name%3A%20string)%3A%20Component%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Registory.registeredConstructors%5Bname%5D()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0Aconst%20registory%20%3D%20new%20Registory()%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20When%20User%20want%20to%20register%20component%20via%20Typescript%20class%0A%0Aclass%20C1%20extends%20Component%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20public%20someProperty%3A%20string%20%3D%20%22Hello%20C1%22%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20public%20f1()%3A%20string%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.baseFunction()%20%2B%20this.someProperty%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0ARegistory.registerComponent(%22C1%22%2C%20C1)%3B%0Aconst%20c1%3A%20Component%20%3D%20Registory.instanciate(%22C1%22)%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20When%20user%20want%20to%20register%20component%20via%20plain%20object%0A%0ARegistory.registerComponent(%22C2%22%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20someProperty%3A%20%22Hello%20C2%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20f1%3A%20function()%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.baseFunction()%20%2B%20this.someProperty%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D)%3B%0Aconst%20c2%3A%20Component%20%3D%20Registory.instanciate(%22C2%22)%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20This%20is%20the%20test%20c1%20and%20c2%20should%20pass%0A%0Aconsole.log(c1%20instanceof%20Component)%3B%0Aconsole.log(c2%20instanceof%20Component)%3B%0Aconsole.log(c1.f1()%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22This%20is%20base%20Hello%20C1%22)%3B%0Aconsole.log(c2.f1()%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22This%20is%20base%20Hello%20C2%22)%3B%0Aconsole.log(c1%20instanceof%20C1)%3B))

Comment: I'm sorry I made your misunderstand. I want to merge properties of plain object into a class generated by instanciating Component. I append some codes describing interfaces I want to achieve. However, thank you for answering.

Comment: Check my revised answer